How to specify a rectangular block of pixels in a video stream by d3d11？
I have successfully rendered my video stream to the window. Now I want to pass in a rectangular coordinate and only display the pixels within this coordinate. How to achieve this with D3D? I have already tried RSSetScissorRects and reset ViewPort, but these all don't work.
Areset ViewPort, it just changes the total graphic' size.
deviceContext_->RSSetScissorRects(1, &newRegion_);

D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    viewport.TopLeftX = static_cast<FLOAT>(area.left);
    viewport.TopLeftY = static_cast<FLOAT>(area.top);
    viewport.Width = static_cast<FLOAT>(area.right - area.left);
    viewport.Height = static_cast<FLOAT>(area.bottom - area.top);
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    
    deviceContext_->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

What's the problem?
